# How to benchmark Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, benchmarks

I have Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I want to benchmark it. I found something called **nbench** but it's old. I need something that measures my CPU, RAM and HDD. I also installed **Phoronix Test Suite** but I search for tests but every one is 500MB+ and I don't have that much space.

What do you recommend?

Comment: What are you attempting to measure, against what, and why?  "Just to have a number" is pretty useless, TBH.  Generally it's better to figure out a task that the machine needs to accomplish, then specifically benchmark **that task** rather than try to accumulate some generic artificial numbers that likely won't translate all that well for any given purpose.

Comment: @JimSalter Dumb question. We compare CPUs with benchmarks to know which one to buy if we want a better one for the actual task...

Comment: [Compilation of Linux server benchmarking scripts](https://github.com/haydenjames/bench-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

[**Geekbench2**](https://www.geekbench.com/)

---

[**3 Open-Source Benchmarking Tools**](http://www.howtogeek.com/111617/how-to-benchmark-your-linux-system-3-open-source-benchmarking-tools/)

1. Hardinfo – CPU Benchmark
2. GtkPerf – GTK+ Benchmark
3. Phoronix Test Suite – Comprehensive Benchmarks

Comment: These all look like GUI applications.

Answer (score 0):

This looks useful:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-benchmark-your-system-cpu-file-io-mysql-with-sysbench

I agree with Jim Salter that the best benchmark is your workload.

However, you might be in a situation where you're testing basic systems with different components, and getting your app running would take more time than a simple shell utility.  If you can correlate your application's behavior with a "just a number" then you can more quickly predict the advantages of different configurations

.... if you know that faster CPU is desired, then having "just a number" to work with can be a lot faster for experimentation than a full workload test.